# Reformat the title of europeCV

Tags: templates, cv, europecv

I am currently building my resume in SHARELATEX, here i am using a Template in Cv or Resume - [EuropeCV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/europecv) (<- Link). In this tex file there is no code to include Title on my CV. for ex I want to put a title as 'curriculum vitae' on the top of my Resume.
Is there any method to do it? I have attached a image.

And I want decrease the length of the line spacing and para spacing. 
[image]

Comment: Please add a link to the template.

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/europecv

Comment: i dont want the logo (europass) and flag pictures, so i have removed those from the main tex file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines with comments are new or modified from [sharelatex example](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/europecv):

```
\documentclass[helvetica,nologo,openbib,totpages]{europecv} %removed notitle, flagCMYK, replaced logo with nologo
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{setspace}%package to control the overall spacing

\makeatletter%
\renewcommand*\ecvtitle{%taken from definition file ecven.def and adapted to requirement 
    \ecv@utf{\Large\textbf{C\ecv@kern u\ecv@kern r\ecv@kern r\ecv@kern
            i\ecv@kern c\ecv@kern u\ecv@kern l\ecv@kern u\ecv@kern m \ecv@kern V\ecv@kern
            i\ecv@kern t\ecv@kern a\ecv@kern e}}
}
\def\ecv@picture[#1]#2{%
    \def\ecvarg{#2}%
    \ifx\@empty\ecvarg\renewcommand*{\ecvdrawpicture}{}\else%
    \renewcommand*{\ecvdrawpicture}{\begin{picture}(80,0)(0,50)\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\end{picture}}%adjust the (0,50) params to fine tune the picture position
    \fi}%
\makeatother%
\setstretch{0.9}% sets the line spacing to 90%

\ecvname{Doe, Joe}
\ecvfootername{Joe Doe}
\ecvaddress{Nowhere in London, England, UK}
\ecvtelephone{12345678}
\ecvfax{12345678}
\ecvemail{\url{email@address.com}}
\ecvnationality{English}
\ecvdateofbirth{Dec 24 1990}
\ecvgender{male}
\ecvpicture[width=2cm]{lion.png}
\ecvbeforepicture{\ecvspace{-1cm}\raggedleft}%reduces the space before the picture => "Personal info" goes up; \raggedleft keeps the picture to the right side
\ecvfootnote{For more information call me}

\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{english}


    \begin{europecv}
        \ecvpersonalinfo[5pt]

        \ecvsection{Work experience}

        \ecvitem{Date}{2010 -- 2013}
        \ecvitem{Occupation or position held}{CV writer, Very Big Company}

        \ecvsection{Education and training}

        \ecvitem{Place and Date}{Very Big University, 2008 -- 2010}
        \ecvitem[10pt]{Title of qualification awarded}{MSc in Nothinglogy}

        \ecvitem{Place and Date}{Big University, 2005 -- 2008}
        \ecvitem{Title of qualification awarded}{BSc in Nothinglogy}


        \ecvsection{Personal skills and~competences}

        \ecvmothertongue[5pt]{English}
        \ecvitem{\large Other language(s)}{French, German}
        \ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
        \ecvlanguage{French}{good}{good}{good}{good}{good}
        \ecvlanguage{German}{good}{good}{good}{good}{good}
        \ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]{(*)}

        \ecvitem[10pt]{\large Social skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
        \ecvitem[10pt]{\large Organisational skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
        \ecvitem[10pt]{\large Technical skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
        \ecvitem[10pt]{\large Computer skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
        \ecvitem[10pt]{\large Artistic skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
        \ecvitem[10pt]{\large Other skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
        \ecvitem{\large Driving licence(s)}{State here whether you hold a driving licence and if so for which categories of vehicle. (Remove if not relevant).}

        \ecvsection{Additional information}
        \ecvitem[10pt]{}{Include here any other information that may be relevant, for example contact persons, references, etc. (Remove heading if not relevant).}

        \ecvitem{}{\textbf{Personal interests}}
        \ecvitem[10pt]{}{Musics, Movies, Golf}

        \ecvitem{}{\textbf{References}}
        \ecvitem{}{Person One, Person Two}

    \end{europecv}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks a lot for the help. Now it's working.

Comment: sir one more change i need here, In the above output fig, I need the lion picture infornt of the personal information. Is this possible? this ll help me to include more things in my resume.

Comment: @prasadak.kle Sure, just uncomment the line `\ecvpicture[width=2cm]{lion.png}`

Comment: but again the personal information section  ll go down. i want the the photo right in-front of the personal information tab

Comment: @prasadak.kle You mean [like this](http://i.imgur.com/m0wJuLG.png) or [like that](http://i.imgur.com/14LZoHJ.png)?

Comment: the image u added as "like this" is the correct way what i wanted!! but can u please give me both scenarios code? (i.e the images with the link like this and like that)

Comment: @prasadak.kle I updated the answer to be "like that"; to make it "like this" remove `\ecvspace{-1cm}` or use another value in place of `-1cm`.

Comment: thankyou very much for your time and support sir. I really appreciate your help and time in answering and helping me.